# Google Maps CanvasLayer + WebGL, display on all maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, webgl

I'm drawing WebGL content on a CanvasLayer (http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/canvaslayer/src/CanvasLayer.js?r=377), everything works fine, pretty much like in this example here: http://build-failed.blogspot.de/2013/02/displaying-webgl-data-on-google-maps.html

So my question is: is it possible to display the CanvasLayer + its WebGL content on all maps (when zoomed out)?

Comment: Don't really understand your question. What do you mean on "all maps"?

Comment: I mean, when you zoom out on the map you see, at some point, multiple "worlds" but the webgl content is only drawn on one of them. So if you reach some zoom level (relative to the window size, so no explicit value possible to say) the webgl-content starts jumping out of the view (altough it maybe gets back in the center at the next zoom). It is possible to add 256 or 512 etc. to every coordinate that is drawn so you can draw multiple webgl-content only to right of the first "map", but not to the left side (by substraction 256, 512, 768...) thats the only thing i found out so far.

Comment: If you are interested in Google Maps API + WebGL, you may want to check this [Using New WebGL-powered Maps Features](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/using-new-webgl-powered-maps-features).